# How to make ActiveViewController-enabled app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios8.3

How to make ActiveViewController-enabled app?

I mean when the user open ActiveViewController in safari,
I want my app is one of the participants. and get message from safari, the link.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set mime type in info.plist, that which document you want to open in your app. for example image, video or word document.

Answer (score 1):

You need the add an "Action Extension" in your project. It's like WatchKit or Today Extension, means you need the add new target in your application (Action Extension).

New > Target... from the File menu. In the left pane, select Application Extension from the iOS section, choose Action extension, and click Next.

You can follow this tutorial :

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794

And tutorial's source code :

https://github.com/tutsplus/iOS8-BuildActionExtension